# How can I confirm if the specified user is following my page in Facebook with graph api?

Tags: facebook, graph, confirmation

my idea is get the followers list and search the id of the user in it.
I tried with param subscribers, but it is been remove after v2.0.
with '{page id}/events' I can not get any information. Who knows how to do that?

Comment: what´s the use case for this? why would you want to know?

Comment: may be you are looking for /{page-id}/likes